# Best way to use Value types as Reference types?

Tags: c#, generics, value-type, reference-type

I've been using something similar to this whenever I needed to reference a Value type:

```
    public class RefHost<T> {
        public RefHost(T val)
        {
            Value = val;
        }
        private T _value;
        public T Value {
            get {
                return _value;
            }
            set {
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm wondering is there a built in way or an easier way to use an existing Value type as a Reference type?

Example:

```
public class Editor {
    public RefHost<int> Blah = new RefHost<int>(5);

    // Some kind of timer to increase the value of Blah every few ticks
}
```

Kind of like that where the user of `Editor` specifies a value type that needs to be changed, and there can be multiple instances of `Editor` each with it's own value. I used the timer as an example but most of the time it's a user control like a slider.

Comment: Well you could use an automatically implemented property to make it significantly smaller. The next question is *why* you use this. While there are *some* cases where I've wanted this, they're very rare...

Comment: What's the bigger picture? Why do you need to? What do you gain?

Comment: For example, if I have a UserControl that's going to be editing a Point or Int which is going to be used by the Parent of the UserControl

Comment: @leaf68 - I still don't get it. Please provide an example of your desired usage.

Comment: Alright, I added an example

Comment: `MyTimer.Update(ref Blah)` should do exactly what you want if `Blah` is an `int`.  See @newStackExchangeInstance's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. If you want to pass it as a reference type to a method just use the `ref` modifier:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int n = 1;
    Test(ref n);
    Console.WriteLine(n); //will print out 2 and not 1.
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
public static void Test(ref int x)
{
    x = 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to store the reference in a variable rather than just as an argument to a method

Comment: @leaf68 - Then why not just store it in a variable and make that variable visible to the called function?

Comment: Because there will be many instances of the class that needs this, and each is going to have it's own Value type that it's going to be editing

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this?

```
public class Editor {
    public int Blah = 5;

    // Some kind of timer, with a handler like:
    void MyTimerTicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Blah += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the provided usage this would work just fine, but I suspect that `MyTimerTicker` is on a different object based on the OP's comments.  +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Boxing and unboxing is what this is called. Your solution might be more type safe though.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replace the property and backing field with a public field.  While it is generally good for classes to use properties rather than fields, the whole *purpose* of your type is to be a simple mutable container for a single value-type instance; the state encapsulated by any reference to an instance of the type should be precisely defined by two things:

1. The value of the `Value` member

   The whereabouts of all other references to the instance that exist anywhere in the universe

If two instances have the same `Value`, and if within the entire universe only one reference exists to each one, the two references should be semantically indistinguishable [since in both cases the set of "other references" that exist to the instances would be empty]

While there are various helper methods that a type of that style might implement, it would be impossible for a future version of the type to add additional state without violating the expected semantics.  Since the whole purpose of the type is to behave like a class object containing a single field of type `T`, code will be clearest if one writes the object to in fact *be* a class object containing a single field of type `T`.

BTW, if you don't want to define a custom type, another option is to use a single-element `T[1]`.  That will use a little bit of extra storage to hold the dimension, and adding `[0]` to all references will be a little uglier than `.Value`, but such an approach will nonetheless work pretty simply.